# Regex to Validate Three Capital Letters then Six Digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm just working on some JavaScript to accept some user input via jQuery. What I'm trying to validate is 3 capital characters followed by 6 integers.

Anyone know how this can be done using a regular expression in JavaScript?

Comment: I can't think of a simpler regular expression. I recommend you invest some time and learn some of the RegExp basics—it'll prove useful in the future.

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide regular expressions, you are wanting *JavaScript* regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified version could be `/^[A-Z]{3}\d{6}$/`.

A more 'compatible' version would be to use  `/^\p{Lu}{3}\pN{6}$/`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex could be:

```
/^[A-Z]{3}\d{6}$/
```

or, if you want to be unicode compatible:

```
/^\p{Lu}{3}\pN{6}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy like this:

```
var match = yourString.match(/^\p{Lu}{3}\pN{6}$/);
if(match) {
    // tada!
} else { alert("not matched"); }
```